# How to track sim card airtime and data pack with the help of python?

Tags: python, automation, sim-card

I have 10 sim cards used by different devices. Sim cards are Telkom (telecommunications provider from South Africa). We have to manually check the airtime and data packs available in all of them, which takes so much time. Is there any way to automate this process? Any way to automate this process with the help of python language so that I can check the airtime and data pack left all of them with the help of a single web app etc. We found that Telkom does not provide any API regarding this to track sim card airtime and data pack.

[image: These are the devices that use the sim card]

**These are the devices that use the sim card**

Answer (score 0):

Without an API from the provider... the short answer is no...

You do have a few options though:

1. Make contact with the cellular provider, they offer business solutions that will allow you to manage a fleet of SIM cards remotely.
2. If you are only using data on these SIM cards, then MTN is SA has a data sharing option which will work out well as each SIM card in a device can be assigned to a "Main Prepaid/Contract SIM" that you keep. From this main sim you can use the App and manage/view how much data each sim uses from one shared bundle. There is no longer a need to manage any data on each sim as they use data from the main sim cards bundle.
3. If you developed the device, you can get the dev guys to send you alerts when airtime is low. (which can be queried locally on the device via USSD code etc).
4. check out https://simcontrol.co.za/